# set min-height for iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, resize

```
    // resize myiframe base on content height
    $('.myiframe').contents().find('body').css({"min-height": "100", "overflow" : "hidden"});
    setInterval( "$('.myiframe').height($('.myiframe').contents().find('body').height() + 20)", 1 );
```

the above code will automatically resize the iframe's height based on content height. The problem is, how do I set the minimum height of the iframe to 500px, if the content height is less than 500px ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Math.max()`.

```
setInterval( function(){
  var height = $('.myiframe').contents().find('body').height() + 20;
  $('.myiframe').height(Math.max(height, 500));
}, 1 );
```

PS. You've using `setInterval` which will run your code every millisecond until the page is unloaded. Change to `setTimeout` or use `clearInterval`.

Comment: so how i'm going to apply Math.max() in the above code? i'm quite new with javascript/jquery